# WhenAny method in task async in .NET 4.5 Never Completes

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm trying out the new `async` and `await` keywords using VS2012RC and .NET 4.5 with just a simple delegate that returns a string, which works fine when I run a single one:

`string message = await Task.Run(() => { return "something"; });`

but when I try `WhenAny`:

`string message = await Task.WhenAny(new Task<string>(() => { return "something"; })).Result;`

it just never completes...why?

I've been watching a video by Steve Sanderson from TechDays 2012 Netherlands which makes this look really easy: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2287

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a `Task` using its constructor, it's not started yet. You have to call `Start()` to actually start it.

I think you should to use `Task.Run()` in your second version too, which returns you a `Task` that's already started.

Also, it's a bad idea to mix asynchronous waiting (`await`) with synchronous waiting (`Result` or `Wait()`), because [it can lead to a deadlock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx).

So, I would write your code as:

```
var task = await Task.WhenAny(Task.Run(() => "something"));
string message = await task;
```

(Of course, there is no reason to use `Task.WhenAny()` when you have only one `Task`, but I'm assuming this is just an example.)

Comment: Right. There's a lot of stuff on `Task` that generally shouldn't be used when writing `async`/`await` code. I have a list at the bottom of my [`async`/`await` intro post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html): `Task` constructor, `Wait`, `Result`, `WaitAny`, and `WaitAll`. Also, `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: For the curious, `Task` started out as the backbone of the Task Parallel Library in .NET 4.0. This is why it has a lot of APIs that are designed from a synchronous CPU-based perspective.